# Tag view that is an <include> layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am declaring a layout and using  to reuse another xml layout.  I need to tag the layout so I can refer to it programmatically.

```
            <include layout="@layout/cell"
                 android:layout_height="48dp"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:tag="0" />
```

When I use findViewByTag("0") null is returned.  If I replace the included layout with the contents of layout/cell it works, which makes me think the 'tag' attribute does not work with included layouts.  Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 0):

As the documention is saying

```
     Tags

    Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information
    that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to 
   views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.
```

Tag are only used for carrying information you specify on it not identifying the layout itself

Comment: Nice find on docs, however in practice you can.  Included in the Android SDK is View.findViewByTag()

Comment: @Patrick I guess tag wont work with numbers.. try using with letters instead. android:tag="id1".. and update me..

Comment: It takes a string, in this case "0".  This exact layout with tags worked before I replaced a reusable layout with <include>

Comment: @Patrick as I thought tag wont work in include and merge.  but you can still use @+id instead to find your include view.